# I'm writing a javascript mp3 player with Node.js but it keeps telling me no such file or diresctory

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

As my question stats, I'm writing a javascript mp3 play that can upload, delete song files.

I write a `server.js` that creates a web service and can also manage song files, and a `main.js` that calls `server.init()`.
But at the moment when ever I run the program it always says `"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'list.txt'`"(list.txt is a file that contains the songs file names) after I run the program.

All my files are in the same folder as the `main.js` and `server.js`.
I just can't figure out where's wrong.

My codes are here:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require("fs");
var qs = require("querystring");
var formidable = require('formidable');

module.exports.init = function(port = 8000){
    http.createServer(function (request, response){
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log(pathname);
        switch(pathname){
            case "/songInsert": songInsert(request, response); break;
            case "/songDelete": songDelete(request, response); break;
            case "/": 
            case "/index": 
            case "/song.html": index(request, response); break;
            //case "/index.html": 
            //case "/default.html": 
            default:
                fs.createReadStream(pathname)
                .on("error", function(e){
                    console.log("Error: %s", e);
                    if(e.code == 'ENOENT'){
                        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                        response.write(pathname + 'File not found');
                        response.end();
                    }
                    else{
                        throw e;
                    }
                })
            .pipe(response);
        }
    }).listen(port, '127.0.0.1', function(){
        console.log('HTTP listening at http://%s:%s/',
        this.address().address, this.address().port);
    });
};

function songInsert(request, response){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(request, function(err, fields, files){
        var oldpath = files.songFile.path;
        var newpath = '/' + files.songFile.name;
        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
            fs.appendFileSync("list.txt", fields.songName + "," + files.songFile.name + "\n");
            index(request, response);
        });
    });
}

function songDelete(request, response){
    var no = qs.parse(url.parse(request.url).query).no;
    var content = fs.readFileSync("list.txt", 'utf8');
    var lines = content.split('\n');
    fd = fs.openSync("list.txt", 'w');
    lines.forEach(function(line, lineNo){
        console.log(line);
        if(line.length > 0)
        if(lineNo == no){
            let song = line.split(",");
            fs.unlink("/" + song[1], function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log(song[1] + ' deleted!');
            });
        }
        else{
            fs.writeSync(fd, line + "\n");
        }
    });
    fs.closeSync(fd);
    index(request, response);
}

function index(request, response){
    var content = fs.readFileSync("list.txt", 'utf8');
    var lines = content.split('\n');
    content = '';
    lines.forEach(function(line, lineNo){
        console.log("line: " + line);
        if(line.length > 0){
            let song = line.split(",");
            content += '<tr>'
                + '<td>' + lineNo + '<td>'
                + '<td>' + song[0] + '<td>'
                + '<td>' + song[1] + '<td>'
                + '<td>'
                + '<input name = "btnPlay" type = "button" value = "播放" mp3file = "' + song[1] + '">'
                + '<input name = "btnDel" type = "button" value = "刪除" mp3no = "' + lineNo + '">'
                + '<td>'
                + '<tr>';
        }
    });
    var html = fs.readFileSync("song.html", "utf8");
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write(html.replace("{{content}}", content));
    response.end();
}
```

And here's the `Node.js` command prompt:

[image]

Comment: have you tried `./list.txt` or `__dirname + "/list.txt"`

Comment: you should try using [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module to resolve file / directories

Comment: @Ashish Modi Yes I did tried

Comment: Hello, I think you should provide the list of your project files. Also instead of having a fixed value of the song list, try to read it from an Enviromental Variable and pass the full path of the `list.txt`  there as well.

For enviromental variables look on: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html